# best way to save and retrieve window scroll position of window using jquery when submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to jquery. I am using php and jquery to do some task. When I submit a form by clicking image button, I want to get the vertical scroll bar position of the window and save it in the browser.  Then I want to retrieve it from window and set the scroll bar position back after page reloaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
  // get the scroll bar position 
  // save the scroll bar position
});
});


$(document).ready(function(){
   If scroll bar position available{
// retrieve the scroll bar position 
// set  the scroll bar position
}
});
```

I found some solution where the scroll bar position is passed in a hidden input filed and then they set the position by getting POST variable. I need to do without passing it in a hidden input filed
Is it possible? Can you help me on it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, use JQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/):

To save data:

```
$("#button").data("KEY","VALUE");
```

To get data:

```
var key=$("#button").data("KEY");
```

By `data()` you can store the scroll position, and get it when it's needed.

Comment: The data might lose after page re-loaded, isn't?

Comment: @Rajesh yes. But we can store it into a cookie if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your reply. I finally did it using sessionStorage. Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":image").click(function(){
        sessionStorage.scrolly=$(window).scrollTop();
  });

  if (sessionStorage.scrolly) {
        $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrolly);
        sessionStorage.clear();
  }
});
```